# How to format text (attributes of elements) in XSLT into one line

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon

Is there any function that can format xslt file. I think he'll probably use somewhere at the beginning. What is my problem?

I created basic xslt:

```
 ...<xsl:template name="model"  match="uml:Model">
        <xsl:element name="uml:Model">
            <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">
              <xsl:value-of select="@xmi:type"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
              <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="visibility">
              <xsl:value-of select="@visibility" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="packagedElement[@xmi:type='uml:Package']">
        <xsl:element name="packagedElement">
            <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">uml:Package</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@xmi:id"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">sequenceD</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="visibility">public</xsl:attribute> 
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>...
```

In first template, everything is fine, attributes of element are in one row. In every next element there are attributes in own line. I don´t know why. **This is XML output:**

```
<uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model" visibility="public">
      <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package"
                       xmi:id="EAPK_9E00FA41_6F28_4e47_9AE6_2A04EE92CDBB"
                       name="sequenceD"
                       visibility="public"/>
</uml:Model>
```

And this is what I am expecting:

```
   <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model" visibility="public">
      <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_9E00FA41_6F28_4e47_9AE6_2A04EE92CDBB" name="sequenceD" visibility="public">
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Collaboration" xmi:id="EAID_AC000001_6F28_4e47_9AE6_2A04EE92CDBB" name="EA_Collaboration1" visibility="public">
         </packageElement>
      </packageElement>
   </uml:Model>
```

I also try to add own text to first template as in second template but with the same result. In xml first element has attributes in one row. Any help, please? Thank you.

Comment: The exact output format is controlled by the XSLT processor. You can somewhat influence it by `<xsl:output indent="yes" />` (or "no", respectively), but what the XSLT processor considers to be indented output is its own thing. Try switching to a different XSLT processor and compare results.

Comment: BTW, `<xsl:element name="uml:Model"><xsl:attribute name="xmi:type"><xsl:value-of select="@xmi:type"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:element>` is a *very* long-winded way of writing `<uml:Model xmi:type="{@xmi:type}" />`. Don't use `<xsl:element>` and `<xsl:attribute>` when the name of the element or attribute is fixed.

Comment: If you have concerns about how the result document should be serialized, then you need to provide your own serializer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Saxon, and specifying indent="yes", then attributes are split onto multiple lines for readability if the line length would otherwise exceed some threshold: the stated purpose of indent="yes" is to make it easier for humans to read the output, and long lines requiring horizontal scrolling are generally considered to result in poor readability.

Saxon (PE and higher) allows you to control the maximum line length using the `saxon:line-length` serialization property, which you can specify on `xsl:output` alongside `indent="yes"`.

Comment: I am using Saxon HE, so I don´t know use to `saxon:line-lenght` . Is there any other options? Why  is everything fine in template model but for next templates is not?

Comment: No, sorry, Saxon extensions to the W3C XSLT specification generally require Saxon-PE or higher. You've asked two supplementary questions in your comment; the StackOverflow format really doesn't encourage that. Ask a new question.

Comment: Whether Saxon's indenter outputs attributes all on one line or one-per-line depends entirely on whether the attributes fit onto one line given the default maximum line length.